# Sort strings using selection sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to create a function that sorts strings, and I've made a function that I think should work, but the `toupper()` function doesn't seem to be having any effect.  Is there something I am missing here?

```
void selectionSort(string array[], int size) {
    int startScan, minIndex;
    string minValue;

    for(startScan=0; startScan<(size-1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];

        for(int index=startScan+1; index<size; index++) {
            string word = array[index];
            toupper(word[0]);
            if(array[index] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not assigning the value `toupper()` returns.

Comment: If you have a problem with `toupper`, why dump the entire sort function on the unsuspecting reader? Also, you probably shoukkd be using `std::vector` and `std::sort` in real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
toupper(word[0]);
```

This statement calculates the value of the expression `toupper(word[0])`, and then throws the result away.

Change it to:

```
word[0] = toupper(word[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the return value of the [toupper()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) function. But anyway, it doesn't do, what you probably think it does (regardless, that `word` is not used afterwards): It will just capital one letter.
What you probably want to do is to capitalize the whole word:

[std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with `toupper` as a parameter can be used.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
void selectionSort(string array[], int size) {
  int startScan, minIndex;
  string minValue;

  for (startScan = 0; startScan<(size - 1); startScan++) {
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];

    for (int index = startScan + 1; index<size; index++) {
      string word = array[index];
      std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::toupper);
      if (array[index] < minValue) {
        minValue = array[index];
        minIndex = index;
      }
    }
    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minValue;
  }
}
```